# How to persist Google Guava BloomFilter into MySql?

Tags: java, jdbc, guava

I am generating some google guava BloomFilters and want to persist them into DB so the other service may be able to get them out of DB later and use it, was wondering what is the best way to do it?

```
    BloomFilter<Integer> filter = BloomFilter.create(Funnels.integerFunnel(), 500, 0.01);

    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    filter.writeTo(baos);
    byte[] bytes = baos.toByteArray();
    ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
```

I could get an inputstream with above code, but seems it's not as elegent as I expected. (I converted output stream to an array and build an input stream with it), any other ideas?

Comment: How elegant do you need it to be? What is deficient about this?

Comment: Converting it to a byte array with `writeTo` seems like an exactly appropriate solution.

Comment: @AndyTurner I was thinking that writing it to a stream then convert it to an array may not necessary......but, seems this is the only way. thanks